# Can someone please explain how all the formatting tools works in VS Code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint, prettier

**Background**

I just get into learning react.js, and find out a lot people are using prettier and eslint to format their code. But after I setup my own based on the online guides, wired things happened. It can format code correctly when I'm saving the file, but not when I manually trigger format function (Shift+option+F). It will format the file to a wired way that eslint will give me errors.

Here's the vscode settings that I'm using:

```
"editor.formatOnSave": true,
"[javascript]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": false
},
"eslint.autoFixOnSave": true,
"eslint.alwaysShowStatus": true,
"prettier.disableLanguages": [
    "js"
],
"editor.detectIndentation": true,
"editor.tabSize": 2,
```

and I also have a .eslintrc file

```
{
"extends": ["react-app", "plugin:prettier/recommended"],
}
```

and a .prettierrc file

```
{
"trailingComma": "es5",
"tabWidth": 2,
"semi": true,
"singleQuote": true,
"jsxBracketSameLine": true
}
```

What I assume here is the vscode keyboard shorcut(Shift+option+F) is not using the same configuration (or even not the same tool) as autoFixOnSave.
But also I don't understand how these tools work and integrated together, and which one overrides which one. Can some one help?

Comment: This [linked article](https://medium.com/app-sapiens/how-to-make-vs-code-work-with-eslint-typescript-and-prettier-3deca7a28cb8) on setting up Priettier w TypeScript helped me. In your `settings.json` file, it instructs you to set Prettier as the default formatter for the languages you want Prettier to format. In your root directory, create a `.prettierrc` and `.eslintrc.js` to setup Prettier's options and ESLint rulles.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you disabling `js` for prettier?

Do you know Prettier can be integrated flawlessly with ESLint?

Take a look at this article: [Prettier: Integrating with ESLint](https://prettier.io/docs/en/eslint.html)

In your user/workspace settings, just add:

```
  "files.autoSave": "off",
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "eslint.autoFixOnSave": true,
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.fixAll": true,
    "source.organizeImports": true
  },
  "eslint.options": {
    "extensions": [".js", ".jsx"]
  },
  "eslint.validate": ["javascript", "javascriptreact", "typescript", "typescriptreact"],
```

Also it is recommended having a `.editorconfig` in your root folder:

```
# http://editorconfig.org

root = true

[*]
charset = utf-8
indent_style = space
indent_size = 2
end_of_line = crlf
insert_final_newline = true
trim_trailing_whitespace = true

[*.md]
max_line_length = off
trim_trailing_whitespace = false
```

And finally, in your `.eslintrc` file, add:

```
"extends": ["react-app", "plugin:prettier/recommended", "prettier/react"],
```

Check out the [eslint-plugin-react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react) for validating react.

Comment: I did exactly what you list above, the issue still exist. And I need the configure that disable vscode format javascript, which is this line: `"[javascript]": {"editor.formatOnSave": false},` other wise the vscode will trying to format on save as a different format, and then eslint or prettier takes in to print the correct format. So I still feel the problem here is vscode editor itself is not using prettier to format the code.

Comment: @Dacredible try putting this in your `settings.json`: `"javascript.implicitProjectConfig.checkJs": false`, `"javascript.validate.enable": false`, `"eslint.enable": true`

Answer (score 0):

I am not looking at the mac version of VS code, but I think that hotkey is supposed to be `Shift + Option + F`

Edit: I usually disable the default javascript formatter in vscode, because it can conflict with my eslint rules, which makes it impossible for eslint to properly format my code.

ESLint has it's own Fix command which does not have a hotkey on my setup, but I have `eslint.autoFixOnSave: true`.

Prettier does not hook into the internal vscode format command. It also has it's own command set up. The default hotkey to run prettier format for the majority of the available prettier extensions is `CMD + Shift + P -> Format Document` but will trigger on save if `editor.formatOnSave` is `true`.

Comment: oh yeah, my bad, I mean shift+option+f. But that's not the main problem